# Stretch Images to screen size in GridLayout Android

Tags: java, android, layout, responsive

I want to strech my cards responisve.
I have a GridLayout with 3 columns. The scaleTypes of the cards are fitXY.

How can i autoscale the cards.  Somehow android:strechmode isn't found.

[image: Cards]

The XML:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="1">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_columnWeight="0"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_columnWeight="0"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_columnWeight="0"
            app:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Does somebody has any ideo.

Thank you very much

Comment: Why don't use ConstraintLayout?

Comment: How does it work with ConstraintLayout? I though its easier if I use the GridLayout because i can set it up with 3 columns and the cards adjust their size.

Comment: The GridLayout is becoming older and ConstraintLayout offers similar layout control, but with much-improved performance. I can provide the solution with ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConstraintLayout with the use of Horizontal chains offers similar layout control, but with much-improved performance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".com.example.actorsapp.activity.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```